# Event delegation failing to attach events in Backbone.js app

Tags: backbone.js

My Backbone.js app has a popup editor view that will be repeatedly closed and reopened as the user makes changes. I'm trying to figure out the cleanest way to implement this, and I'm stuck on an event delegation issue.

I believe the problem lies in the way I'm applying the template in my `render` method. I haven't had any issues with getting events to fire in other views, but those views differed in that they had a model. The view I'm having issues with is more of an application view that contains sub-views, so I'm not sure how to pass the view's context to the `MyApp` view.

Here's my code:

```
MyApp = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    template: _.template($('#app-template').html()),

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this);
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
      $('#container').html(this.template);
      return this;
    },

    events: {
      "click .save" : "onSaveClicked"
    },

    onSaveClicked: function () {
        console.log("Save clicked.");
        this.$el.remove();
    }
});

$('#show').click(function () {
    var myapp = new MyApp;
});
```

I've also posted it as a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshearl/WBPqk/15/).

I stepped through the Backbone.js source, and it appears that `render` is called first, then `events` are assigned, which is what I'd expect. Everything looks OK from what I can tell, but `onSaveClicked` never fires when I click Save.

The desired functionality is that clicking Show displays the form and Save removes it. If there's a better way to do this that's more inline with Backbone's underlying philosophy I'm open to that as well. You'll notice that I'm nesting an unnamed `div` inside `container`, and that's because I wanted to maintain a consistent anchor point for my popup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The events are bound to the view el, but you never append the el to the DOM. Try

```
MyApp = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    template: _.template($('#app-template').html()),

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this);
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
      this.$el.html(this.template);
      return this;
    },

    events: {
      "click .save" : "onSaveClicked"
    },

    onSaveClicked: function () {
        console.log("Save clicked.");
        this.$el.remove();
    }
});

$('#show').click(function () {
    var myapp = new MyApp;
    $("#container").append(myapp.$el);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WBPqk/18/

Note that in your Fiddle you bound the click event to .save where your template uses a done class.

Comment: also, the use of a jQuery selector as part of the value of the `template` attribute is likely to fail. See this: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/11/09/backbone-js-object-literals-views-events-jquery-and-el/

Comment: Excellent--thanks, @nikoshr. I was just rendering the template HTML, not the actual view. Makes sense.

Comment: I'll be reviewing your post in depth, @derick-bailey. Thanks!